# Windows 7 Printing to a network printer

Tags: windows-7, group-policy, printing, print-server

We have a print server running Windows Server 2008.
Clients that use Windows XP with a logon script to map have no problems printing.
When I test printing to a network printer on a Windows 7 machine, it works fine up to a few machines. As soon as I get 12-15 workstations trying to print, when they log in, they get the yellow exclamation mark and need troubleshooting against the printer name.
It is being deployed by group policy. I have tried to deploy it by group policy, group policy preferences, and using a script and I get the same error whatever I try.
Does anyone have any suggestions to try and troubleshoot?
Once again, Windows XP clients have no issues printing at all.
It is only with Windows 7 clients.
Thanks

EDIT

I have found that the spooler is not starting because you can't add the printer manually either.

Comment: What's it say in the event log?

Comment: of the workstation or server?

Comment: Are the Windows 7 workstations a mix of 32 and 64 bit?

Comment: @JohnnyV - Both?

Comment: Nothing significant in event log on either.
I only noticed a problem with the citrix printer service. That is why I foud the service was causing issues (it is the remains of the offline plugin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an article online that explained how to deploy printers using group policy through a 2008 print server. it was quite easy in the end.
I was overcomplicating things with scripts etc.

Comment: Have you got a link to the article?  I would find that valuable...

Comment: I wish i did post it because I cant find the bookmark anymore lol.If I find the one i am after I will post it.